# Proper way to do permanent thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I want to implement a permanent thread:

```
static Thread thread;
```

that is created when the application starts e.g. by:

```
// Prepare new thread
thread = new Thread(() => Update());

// Compute upper half of pixels on newly created thread
thread.Start();

// Wait until thread is properly initialized
while (!thread.IsAlive);
```

and only ends when the application is terminated by:

```
// End thread
thread.Join();
```

However, the problem is that the worker method Update() should only be called every x seconds. Is there a proper way to Pause the thread. How can individual methods be called "in" the thread or do I have to have a while(true){} in the Update() method that calls these methods?

Could any problem arise from a read-only access to data shared with the main thread?

Comment: I an not sure, that i understand the question, but i think `Timer` whould help you. It runs some code in different thread at specified intervals. You can start with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

To call a method every `x` seconds, don't manually make a thread, use `System.Timers`. For example:

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(15000);
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((_, e) => 
    Console.WriteLine("Timer event at {0}", e.SignalTime));
```

The example in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Have a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) that is used to signal when the thread should stop. Then in the thread wait on it for x seconds. If it isn't signaled then do the `Update`, otherwise exit the thread:

```
ManualResetEvent exitUpdateThread = new ManualResetEvent(false);

void UpdaterThread()
{
  while(exitUpdateThread.Wait(timeBetweenUpdates) == false)
  {
    Update();
  }
}

Thread thread = new Thread(() => UpdatesThread());
```

Where `timeBetweenUpdates` is how often you want to update. Now, when you want to terminate the thread you just set the event and wait for the thread to exit:

```
exitUpdateThread.Set();
thread.Join();
```